# How many nodes in a K-ary tree with L leaf nodes

Tags: graph, tree, complexity-theory, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Assuming that we have a k-ary tree with L leaf nodes, can the average number of nodes in the tree be calculated if we were to know the average number of children for each node? If not, what other information would be required to make this calculation?

Comment: You can follow this link to more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree
If the average number of children for each node is denoted by `a` and height of the tree by `h`, the average number of tree node would be `a^(h+1) - 1` which is equal to `a*L - 1`.